# List Git commit SHAs from a specific branch without cloning the repository

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Is there a way to get all the commit IDs for a particular branch without cloning the repository or using the API's?

I'm looking for something like this. Unfortunately the below command works only within the repository (i.e., git directory). I want to able to do it without cloning the repo.

```sh
git rev-list --remotes=*master
```

For example, the below command brings all the branches and it's last commit ID (**Note:** the command works without having to clone the repo.)

```sh
git ls-remote -h http://user:password@example.gitlab.com/ProjectA/example.git
```

Sample output:

```
82cd0dcc9d1005b44bdc799034b706f9ad2b1e0e    refs/heads/master
afacc961fedf49a84c09ab91e67633b02921dd07    refs/heads/projects/myproject
b6d954ec86750dcfd35c1c3fba4f40449abeb6ed    refs/heads/releases/production
e891a0b29847d0d7dfc5bc7e5ad45f718918f67f    refs/heads/releases/ready_for_prod
7b0282004a6f72c5803ddf19172c16a0b3124038    refs/heads/releases/test
```

Comment: `git rev-list a` *will* get all the commit IDs for branch `a`... since I guess that's *not* what you want... you'll have to specify a bit

Comment: Sorry updated my question ...hopefully it clarifies it.

Comment: Do you want to list branches and output the commit hash of their tip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible using regular Git commands, but you've tagged your question with both [github](/questions/tagged/github) and [gitlab](/questions/tagged/gitlab), both of which have APIs that let you do it:

- [GitHub](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository): `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits` and provide a parameter `sha` containing the name of the branch whose commits you wish to list
- [GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#list-repository-commits): `GET /projects/:id/repository/commits` and provide a parameter `ref_name` containing the name of the branch whose commits you wish to list

You may need to be using GitLab Enterprise Edition to use its API. (The version hosted at GitLab.com should support it.)

Comment: I need to buy one of these crystal balls you guys have :-) I didn't get past the "This only brings all the branches only" enigma.

Comment: @Chirs, I just updated my question. I actually didn't want to use any APIs. As our client could be using github, gitlab or bitbucket (Just didnt want to base it on that we wont be able to maintain that if they modify their API's). I was looking for a straight git command. But from what I hear its not possible.

Comment: @Dinesh, then you're out of luck. There is no way to list all commits on a branch on a remote repository without fetching from it using just Git itself. The best you'll be able to do is the commit at the tip of each remote ref (mostly branches and tags).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to interact with a repository you will need to clone it first.

Once cloned, run:

```
git rev-list branch/name
```

Comment: Sorry just updated my question - I want to able list the commit ID without clone the repo. But based on @Chirs's above comments not possible.

Answer (score 0):

To get the output you asked for, a `for-each-ref` would be easier to format :

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(objectname) %(refname)" refs/heads/
```

Comment: Is it possible to specify a  Repo URL parameter to this command?

Comment: From your comments on Chris' answer, I'm not sure you even *have* the repo it's meant to be run on. If not, I can't see a way to get what you want...

Comment: Right..  At least I know its not possible. thanks for the help.